# Direction of x-axis with respect to y-axis in Cartesian coordinate system?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, graph-theory

What should be the direction of y-axis with respect to x-axis in cartesian coordinate system ?

It should be on right hand side or left hand side of x-axis or it can be on both sides as long as it is perpendicular to x-axis ?

Plus

Angles in counterclockwise rotation are considered positive when they are measured from positive x-axis. What if the rotation is clockwise ? From which axis the angles will be considered positive if the rotation is clockwise ?

Comment: Our universe is a left handed one, so you rotate 90 degrees anti-clockwise to get the y axis.

Comment: great @PiyushDivyanakar. ans what about angles if the rotation is clockwise?

Comment: if angles go anti-clockwise it is the left handed system. If they clockwise it is the right handed system. The rule is the same, you rotate 90 degrees(depending on handedness).

Comment: look at this link please they take y axis at clock wise rotation with respect to x-axis. are they wrong ?. https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Geometry_for_Elementary_School/Rectangular_coordinate_system

Comment: It is correct. It is a matter of convention.

Comment: suppose a system is rotating ?then will we take y-axis on counter clockwise direction if the body is rotating counter clockwise. and we will take y in clockwise direction if the body is rotating clockwise ? @PiyushDivyanakar

Comment: @PiyushDivyanakar it is not *entirely* a matter of convention.

Answer (score 3):

It is solely matter of convention, in one case we talk of [**Right Hand System**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-hand_rule) in the second of **Left Hand System**, note indeed that we need also to fix a z axes direction to define a clockwise and a counterclockwise direction for rotation.

[image]

[image]

Comment: please expain in two dimensions. only x-y. kindly tell me is there a rule that tells us when to use right hand coordinates and when to use left hand coordinates while applying them ?

Comment: @Alex In 2 dimension all system are equivalent since you cannot distinguish them, fixed x, say on the right, we can choose y up or down and those are equivalent choices. Otherwise in 3 dimension we can have 2 kinds of reference systems and we have to declare which one we are referring to.

Comment: suppose a system is rotating ?then will we take y-axis on counter clockwise direction if the body is rotating counter clockwise. and we will take y in clockwise direction if the body is rotating clockwise?

Comment: To define a clockwise direction we need to fix a direction for the z axes, otherwise we can’t distinguish one system from another. The usual convention is consider a RHS with z axes up out of the plane, with x axes direction on the right, in this case y axes direction is up.

Answer (score 2):

The $x$-axis (also known as the *abscissa*) goes horizontally and the $y$-axis (also known as the *ordinate*) goes vertically. This is because, $$\begin{align} x &= \text{ the independent variable; and} \\ y &= \text{ the dependent variable.}\end{align}$$ This means that from these, we can measure data (typically for scientific purposes) and graph equations. When conducting a science experiment, we look at cause and effect, and how $$\text{Cause}\longrightarrow\text{Effect}.$$ Here, there are two variables in our experiment. The variable that creates the cause, namely $x$, and the variable that becomes the effect of that cause, namely $y$. $$\underbrace{\text{Cause}}_{x} \longrightarrow\underbrace{\text{Effect}}_{y}.$$ It follows, then, that the variable $y$ depends on that of $x$, and so is *dependent*, with $x$ being vice versa (namely *independent*).

There are other elements under investigation during a scientific experiment, but this is where the graph originated from, and we just applied it mathematically by writing out an *equation* to describe the relationship between the cause and effect (the $x$ variable to the $y$ variable). For different forms of equations, we have different relationships. For example, the equation $$y = mx + c$$ describes the *linear* relationship between $x$ and $y$. And the equation, $$y = ax^2 + bx + c$$ describes the *quadratic* relationship between $x$ and $y$. We graph these equations from plotting points on our graph, for which their position on the graph corresponds to an $x$ point and a $y$ point. We represent this as a *coordinate* $(x, y)$. Notice that this word derives from the word *ordinate* which is the $y$-axis. However, when we have a coordinate $(x, y)$ that is not plotted on the graph, this is known as an *ordered pair*. This is necessary because we can write equations like, $$\text{Find $(x, y)$ over the integers if $y^2 = 2x^2 - 1$}.\tag*{$\bigg(\begin{align} &\text{This is a negative Pell} \\ &\text{equation by the way.}\end{align}\bigg)$}$$ Now we also have a third axis, namely the $z$-axis, to form *ordered triplets* $(x, y, z)$. This is the final axis, for the Cartesian Plane measures our dimensions only in space, namely $3$, and that’s where equations can get a bit more interesting, but when measuring scientific data, we stick with $x$ and $y$.

Go [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abscissa_and_ordinate) to find out more if you still don’t quite understand.