# X & Y planes of two dimentional Cartesian system.

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I found that sometimes y-axis is shown perpendicular with x-axis at counterclockwise direction but sometimes y-axis is shown perpendicular with x-axis at clockwise rotation. What is the difference between them ?

What comes in my mind is that for a counterclockwise rotation of a system they put y-axis perpendicular in counter clockwise direction w.r.t x-axis to define any function related to that system

&

for a clockwise rotation of a system they put y-axis perpendicular in clockwise direction w.r.t x-axis to define any function related to that system.

Am i right ? Kindly share your thoughts with me on this.[image]

Comment: Short answer: $x$ and $y$ are just arbitrary names. We can name the axes $a$ and $b$, or exchange the names arbitrarily. There is no meaning in it. A function does not have to be $y(x)$, it can be $x(y)$ or $a(b)$. So name your axes whatever you want and need.

Comment: Your first diagram ... the vertical line is labeled "$y$-axis", but has a letter $x$ at the top.  That is probably an error.

Answer (score 1):

For 2D coordinate systems there is not substantial difference with the two systems it is purely a matter of convention.

For 3D coordinate systems we can distinguish between **Right Hand System** and **Left Hand System**.

Refer also to this  [MSE OP](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2656604/505767) for more details.